# How to recover my lost cryptomultipler money?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, fraud

I was trading in a cryptomultipler some one shared with me, to invest my money in there. They told me that my investment will grow, but after that they been asking me many charges until I sent them more than $1150, but until now they never gave me any profit. Please help me to recover my money.

Answer (score 5):

You are the victim of a scam by criminal conmen.

You cannot recover your money.

The bitcoin system does not allow for cancellations, reversals or refunds of transactions where payments were made due to fraud. The only person who can return your money is the person who you gave it to. Criminals almost never voluntarily return what they stole. The bitcoin system does not allow for tracing or identification of recipients, The system intentionally makes this very difficult.

You will now be contacted by other conmen claiming they can help you recover your money. They might claim to be someone who was tricked and who found someone who recovered their money for them. They will all be lying to you in order to trick you out of more money. Ignore them.

I suggest you report this fraud to the local police, but accept that your money has all gone forever and will never be recovered.

---

This kind of theft happens often. Here are a few similar questions:

- [Refunding of payments if scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96430/13866)
- [I lost my BTC from 3 USA BTC traders](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96234/13866)
- [Financial Department Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96170/13866)
- [I think I was scammed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96046/13866)
- [Bitcoins missing following wrong bank account number entered](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95852/13866)
- [Trading Bitcoins through binary miner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95646/13866)
- [How did lose my bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95383/13866)
- [Trying to locate my bitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95099/13866)
- [Recovery of scammed funds](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93390/13866)